# How to get 3D coordinates (XYZ) of the sun given Azimuth and altitude/elevation?

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems

I want to create an Augmented Reality(AR) application to show the sun's position where I need the 3D(XYZ) coordinates to plot in Augmented Reality(AR).

Main question: I need to calculate the 3D coordinates(XYZ) from the sun Azimuth and altitude/elevation

Look at the image.

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific, what is the AR?

Comment: Hi @dmtri, Edited the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: Ok, but where can maths be helpfull with your task? I mean you may elaborate more on this, so somenone could assist you

Comment: Hi @dmtri, Edited the question again.

Comment: Thank you @Warlock of Firetop Mountain for the solution that you commented on to my question. This is the solution what I was looking for: x = R * cos(ϕ) * sin(θ) y = R * cos(ϕ) * cos(θ) z = R * sin(ϕ) Where R is the distance of the point from the origin, θ (the azimuth), and ϕ (the elevation).